# How to use Translate behavior and .po file to change dynamic text Cakephp3?

Tags: static, internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.0, behavior

I'm using translate behavior in cakephp 3 using I18n table. Everything is working fine. But if I use .po file to translate static text the content coming from the database won't change.

Can you please help me how to use both Translate behavior and .po file to change dynamic and static text.
I used the following code for the translation:

```
echo  __($name);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this using __d() function. This allows you to override the current domain for a single message lookup.

Use `__d(<your variable>, <domain>);`

For example

```
   echo  __d($name, 'default');
```

default is your .po filename;

Comment: What is that 'default'? Since, I am using session variable to set the config language but the issue I am seeing is that it is translating Flash messages properly but not the headings and other messages written in templates files. Any idea of this issue?

Comment: default is the po file name. Have you used __(<your message>) for your headings and other messages?

Comment: Yeah. I did that. Even "Not Found" message on error page is showing translated. But, nothing else.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to translate the content without creating I18n database table?